# Looking for a CMS for portal-like site

Tags: content-management-system, blogs

I have a new customer, a mall, that wants one or two pages with news, directions to shops, etc. This no problem for me. The problem is that when a shop is added to the site it needs to automatically create a sub-site where the shop can create their content.
Normally I work with Tridion, but the customer can't afford a license, so I need an open-source alternative.

What are your suggestion?

Thanks,

W.

Answer (score 3):

Expression engine is a great option because it has a multi-site features.

It's very flexible and widely used, check it out